# push key generated in firebase not equal one being retrieved android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve the push key that is being generated when i am sign up and creating a new user in my android app. But the key being retrieved is not the same as the one that was created.How is this possible? This is my code.How do i correct it?

```
 firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        //checking if success
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                              id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                             key = databaseReference1.child(sexs).push().getKey();
                            Log.d("User key", key);
                            User user = new User(username, halls, levels, downloadUrl, id, key );




                            databaseReference1.child(sexs).push().setValue(user);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be confusing Firebase Authentication user IDs (often called UID) with Firebase Database push IDs (generate when you call `push()` in a DatabaseReference. They are very different beasts - pretty much the only things they have in common is that they identify something and thus are made to be unique.

If I understand your code correctly, you want to store the newly created user's information in the Firebase Database. The code for that is:

```
databaseReference.child(id).setValue(user);
```

**Update**:

Every time you call `push()` it will generate a new location with a new unique ID. Since your code calls `push()` twice (once where you extract the key and once where you set the value to the database), those will be two separate locations.

To get the key for the location, make sure you call `push()` only once:

```
id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
User user = new User(username, halls, levels, downloadUrl, id, key );

DatabaseReference newRef = databaseReference1.child(sexs).push();
key = newRef.getKey();
Log.d("User key", key);
newRef.setValue(user);
```

Comment: No please! i do understand the difference very much. i want to retrieve the push ID generated after i call the push() in "databaseReference1.child(sexs).push().setValue(user);". This code is supposed to be doing that "key = databaseReference1.child(sexs).push().getKey();" but the value i'm getting is different. I dont understand why @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a different key because you are calling `push()` again

```
databaseReference1.child(sexs).push().setValue(user);
```

Instead you should do the following:

```
databaseReference1.child(sexs).child(key).setValue(user);
```

This will store the user under the key which you generated and stored in the 'key' variable